# Why won't my minecart spawner spawn minecarts?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm attempting to make a Spawner which will generate Minecarts. The command I'm using is:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:"MinecartRideable"}
```

That certainly creates a Spawner with a Minecart inside, but it never spawns one. On the other hand, if I make a Cow Spawner:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:"Cow"}
```

it starts spawning Cows just fine. Why are Minecarts different?

I'm running Minecraft 1.7.9, single-player creative, with cheats.

Comment: Mod spawners are designed to do... Just that. If I remember right, creating a mob spawner to spawn a non-mob entity would crash the game.

Comment: @peper757 not the case. Vechs uses a minecart spawner in inferno mines (custom map)

Comment: @shanodin I'm assuming no mods are required to play the map.

Comment: @peper757 none.  It is vanilla.

Comment: @shanodin Then, I've got nothing.

Comment: @shanodin I think that actually spawned skeletons *riding* minecarts. I'm not sure that you can spawn just a minecart with a spawner. You can definitely spawn mob stacks, including mobs riding minecarts and boats though.

Comment: @Unionhawk you're totally right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you cannot spawn Minecarts like this is because of the way Minecart spawning work. As you know, a spawner only spawns items IF its spawning condition is correct.

For a Minecart (or boat etc.), the spawning requirement is that it is placed by a player activating it on a rail (of any sort).
Because a spawner IS NOT a player, it cannot spawn it. Thus, the Minecart SaveGameID "MinecartRidable" is not usable because it is a placeholder of the original Minecart SaveGameID (which switches to MinecartRidable the moment it's placed/spawned), is "Minecart".

I've also tried it with tracks all around the Minecart spawner, which does not work because again, Minecarts must be placed (activated; right clicked on rails).
Boats work because they behave like a spawn egg. Only, that it will only spawn in water.

*EDIT: The reason it worked is because Boats and Minecarts do not have a spawning requirement in older versions...* (I'm not sure which, but I think it's around 1.2 Release) *Now, only items such as throwable potions and experience orbs do not have a spawn requirement.*

Comment: Aha! Does this mean there's no way to get a Minecart Spawner to work in current versions of Minecraft, or is there a workaround?

Comment: Seeing that you are already using commands, you could always spawn in your Minecarts directly using command blocks on a clock. Alternatively, since Skeletons in Minecarts are possible: Try using that, coupled with a skeleton killing command block, i.e. `/kill @e[(skeletons in the right place)]`. That might leave just the minecarts.

Comment: @Peeja - Yes, there is no way to get spawners to work.
However, as MrLemon said: You can use command blocks (on a clock) to spawn mobs riding minecarts as the minecart that the mob is riding actually despawns (as its own seperate entity) and joins up with the mob riding it. (It can be found in the riding mob's NBT as a compound tag called "Riding", followed by the minecart properties inside it.)

EDIT: Try `/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:mob_Spawner {EntityId:Pig,{Riding:{id:MinecartRidable}}}` - I haven't tested it. Oh, and don't forget to kill the pigs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a shot in the dark with this, but you know how slimes have to spawn in a swamp/slime chunk and mobs have to spawn in dark places?  That is, from mob spawners.


I'm thinking that minecarts have to spawn on rails, correct me if I'm wrong.


EDIT: OP told me this doesn't work...  :(

Comment: Ah, an excellent thought, but I do have rails down next to it. :)

Comment: @Peeja, erm...  I have no idea beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use MCEdit and SethBlings filters. check youtube or [sethblings](http://sethbling.com) website. also you will need rail fir it to spawn.